# Qt/C - QWebView - Loading Flash Lite plugin

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, qml, qwebview

I have problem loading Flash Lite plugin on N8

I have simple QWidget with QWebView inside, whole page (for example Youtube video) is loaded, but instead of video I see "Upgrade your flash player to newer version" (not literally translated)

In code (using Qt 4.7.3):

(_webView is Ui instance of QWebView)

```
ui->_webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
ui->_webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, true);
ui->_webView->load(_url);
```

Request more details, if I haven't provided

Best regards
Marek Sebera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See divanov's post #9 here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?207264-Embed-Flash-player-on-QWebview) -- the "Product Specialist" says

> Webkit doesn't support Flash Lite, it just normal Flash

<del>Although that was in 2009, so I guess this could have changed. Are your libraries up-to-date?</del>

This is [an unresolved bug](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTWEBKIT-155) (in [two parts](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTWEBKIT-155)) on the other hand [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51879) seems to imply that Flash Lite does have some support on Symbian.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do that for global settings.

```
 QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration (true);
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, true);
```

Then use webview to load the youtube video.